# Call to get endpoint succeeding on Postman but failing via curl or Python requests

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests, postman

I'm sending a get request to the Twitter base endpoint that returns HTML markup for the page. It is the initial request sent on every visit to twitter.com.

When no cookies are set in the browser and visiting twitter.com this request returns a status code 302 (can be seen using Chrome DevTools) it is then redirected and returns a status code 200.

When copying the curl (bash) request from Chrome DevTools and pasting it to Postman, I'm receiving a status code 200, and some cookies are sent as a response as well.

However, when executing the raw curl which goes as follows:

```
curl --location 'https://twitter.com/' \
--header 'authority: twitter.com' \
--header 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
--header 'accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
--header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
--header 'pragma: no-cache' \
--header 'referer: https://twitter.com/i/flow/login' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
--header 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
--header 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
--header 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
--header 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
--header 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
```

I receive the following curl response: `curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed`

Using Postman, you can transfer the current request into an exact copy of it using the Python Requests library by going to `Code > Code snippet` in Postman. This results in the following translation of the request:

```
import requests

url = "https://twitter.com/"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'authority': 'twitter.com',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'pragma': 'no-cache',
  'referer': 'https://twitter.com/i/flow/login',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.cookies)
```

However, this returns an empty `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`

My question is, what's the difference between the postman request and the requests made through curl and Python Requests? Why is Postman returning the desired cookies and Python Requests not? Does it have something to do with the initial redirection (302) that can be detected when using Chrome DevTools?

Comment: what do you get if you add `--verbose` to curl? where does it redirect curl?

Comment: Thanks, @hanshenrik. This seems to return the desired cookies, as after various HTTP/2 302 responses the server answers with a set-cookie header, that contains the cookies I just need. I'm not posting the full response here, as it is quite large. However, I need a solution for this using Python Requests.

Comment: It seems like that the server is performing multiple 302's before responding with a cookie or set-cookie header. However, when sending this via Python Requests, I immediately receive a 200, but without cookies or set-cookie header.